# How to achieve transaction concept while dealing with multiple Azure resources in sequence

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb, distributed-transactions, azure-storage-queues

In my application while creating new user record via POST/users REST webapi endpoint, below are the steps involved

step 1: create entry in Azure Active Directory(AAD)

step 2: on success of step:1, send email notification to the concern user email id about user creation in our application (this functionality has been implemented using Azure storage queue & sendgrid). At present failure of step2 wont rollback step1

step 3: on success of step:2, create user document in our Azure cosmos db.At present failure of step3 wont rollback step2 or step1

All these above 3 steps has to be treated as unit of work they must be all success or all fail together like db transaction/rollback. There shouldn't be a situation one step get succeed while other steps failed as it will end up in creating dirty records.

What would be the best/effective ways of achieve **all success or all fail together** kind of implementation, for the above mentioned 3 steps which involves 3 various Azure resources?

Comment: There is no built-in transaction management between any of these services, so this really is up to you to implement for your particular needs. As such, this question is off-topic here, as it's too broad. Also, please note that there is no guaranteed response time on questions here (the answers are posted voluntarily). There's no need to post follow-up comments urging people to answer (and your question was only active for about an hour before you posted that comment).

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism I'm aware of to perform transactions across different Azure resources like you describe. The only place true transactions apply is with the database services and perhaps some others, but not across disparate services.

Given this, your code would need to handle failure cases and cleanups appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Even Cosmos DB alone only has very limited transaction support. If your transactions span several distributed services. you will need to implement your own transactions. Often however, it's not worth the trouble. Consider if it would be sufficient to periodically scan for any inconsistencies and clean up then.

If you do need transactions, you could implement a Resource Manager to use the .NET features from `System.Transactions`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-a-resource-manager) for a starting point.